# Why don't I get compiler errors from returning from a void function template?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider:

```
void f() {
    return 5;
}
```

The above will raise errors. But why not this?:

```
template <typename = void> void f() {
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with gcc-4.5.1. Why does it make a difference using templates such that I wouldn't receive errors from doing the same illegal return statement as a non-template function?. The only setback I get is that I can't call the function (i.e `f()`) without getting:

> `error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'`

But still, what could be the reason that I am able to define a return statement for a void function template?

Here is the code I have:

```
template <typename = void> void f() {
    return 0;
}

// pass

int main() {



}
```

The above code will pass despite a presumably illegal return statement in a function returning void.

Comment: You'll get +1 if you provide an actual testcase. We're having to guess at what you are and are not doing with the template `f()`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I updated.

Comment: That's the code where you get the error as expected. How about when you _don't_, as _not expected_ i.e. the focus of the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quality of implementation issue. The particular quote from the standard would be:

> 14.6/8 [...] If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. [...]

That is, your program is ill formed because that template cannot be used to generate any *valid* specialization, but the compiler is not required to diagnose this. When at a later time you instantiate the template, the compiler must generate the specialization, that specialization is not valid and the compiler complains.

You don't get an error in the template definition because the compiler is following the *no diagnostic required* path, i.e. ignoring the problem until it can no longer ignore it in the instantiation.

Comment: I would have interpreted the quote to mean that if the template isn't valid for any possible type then the template is ill-formed, not that a single invalid type makes it ill-formed.

Comment: @MarkB: I interpret the quote exactly as that: if the template isn't valid for any possible type then the template is ill-formed. That is the case in the question: `template <typename T>` **void** `f() { return 0; }` --> Regardless of the type `T` the function returns `void` and there is a `return 0;`

Comment: Let me get this straight. Does this mean that a compiler *can* generate an error even if I don't instantiate the template?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yes, it means that the program is incorrect and a compiler can reject the program. It is allowed *not* to diagnose the problem, but the code is incorrect.

Comment: So I have two compilers, both standard comforming, and one compiles it while the other can reject it? The ***** of the c++ standard always amazes me.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That will always be the case. In this particular rule, for example, the violation in the question is simple, but it could be something more convoluted that depended on the instantiating types and there being no possible combination. Because the complexity make this undecidable, the standard adds the *no diagnostic required* tail, and then compilers can just take it and avoid diagnosing even simple cases. Note that this does not make a huge difference: if the template is not used, you don't really care that much, if it is used, it will fail the specialization.

Comment: I understood that part, what stumps me is this unnecessary layer of complexity... The standard could simply say "no diagnostics should be done until instantiation".

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Then you are precluding compilers that can fail to compile the code --which it is incorrect as it will never yield a valid specialization. I as a programmer prefer the language allowing a compiler to catch the error than a language the explicitly says that I must wait until instantiation, considering that in many cases (member functions of class templates) they might not be used frequently.

Comment: I prefer a language with the principle of least surprise, a language with consistent rules.. if one compiler compiles my program then I expect it to compile with another one (UB is a different issue, I'm only talking about compilation now)... off.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Undefined Behavior is not a different issue. Most of the UB in the language are errors that the compiler cannot diagnose, it is exactly this issue: the program is ill-formed but the compiler is allowed not to diagnose the issue. Note that this is quite different from *unspecified*, or *implementation defined*.

Comment: ...well, UB is atually compile time not/hardly diagnosable **and** a strict expected behaviour would create additional runtime overhead (yes, there are some exceptions, where the runtime check is almost impossible, but that's the minority of the cases). and for the second reason, for a language like c++, it makes perfect sense. the rule we talk about, on the other hand, still doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the checks are only done when you instantiate the template.

This is usually a good thing, as a code could work fine with one kind of template argument but fail to compile with another one. If you have template overloading, the compiler will even ignore candidates that fail to compile, see [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

Comment: @Kos What does `template void f()` do?

Comment: @David: Causes instantiation in a way that's not entirely clear to the first-time reader!

Comment: [Instantiates the template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477(v=vs.80).aspx), exactly that :)

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading: the program is ill-formed even if the template is never instantiated. The fact that most compilers use the *no diagnostic required* annotation in the standard and ignore the issue is a completely different issue. In particular, there is no value in ignoring this error until the template is instantiated: once the definition is seen the compiler can bail out and avoid the extra cost of processing.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas when is the program ill-formed? Something like "If for *arbitrary* template parameters it's impossible to instantiate  a template, then the program is ill-formed"?

Comment: @Kos: I have the quote in my answer, but basically it means: if there is no type `T` that will yield a valid instantiation, then the template is ill-formed.

Answer (score 7):

[You *do*](http://ideone.com/PHxUJ5):

```
template <typename = void> void f() {
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    f<int>();
}
```

> prog.cpp: In function 'void f() [with  = int]':
>   prog.cpp:7:12:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:2:12: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'

Though the program is still *ill-formed*, the compiler is choosing not to diagnose the semantic error (which is its prerogative) because you're never actually instantiating that function.

Comment: Whether the template is used or not does not matter, the program is ill-formed even with no instantiation but the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: [I'm not sure about that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257103/is-this-program-ill-formed-despite-sfinae)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I have posted the quote from the standard 14.6/8 in an answer.