# Is this program ill-formed despite SFINAE?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sfinae

```
template <typename T> void f() {
    return 0;  // returning value from function returning `void`
}

int main()
{
    // Not instantiating or calling any f<T>()
}
```

In comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255869/560648), [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36565/david-rodriguez-dribeas) asserts that a function template that contains a semantic error and is not instantiated causes a program to be ill-formed:

> Whether the template is used or not does not matter, the program is *ill-formed* even with no instantiation but the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

Conversely, I am quite sure that SFINAE, as well as preventing type deduction and therefore instantiation of the function template per `[C++11: 14.8.2/8]`, allows the program to remain well-formed. however I cannot find any text in this standard paragraph that explicitly says so.

**Who is correct?**

---

Wikipedia, which I shall not consider authoritative for this question, says about a slightly different case:

> [..] SFINAE was introduced **to avoid creating ill-formed programs** when unrelated template declarations were visible [..]

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: I don't see what SFINAE has to do with this. The error in the program is independent of the template arguments.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You're right; that's the answer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Not really "interesting" - the answer was not displayed on my screen at the time we began discussing the issue in comments to a different answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It must have been a glitch in the page, as I provided the answer before I wrote the comment :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: No glitch - I don't press F5 every ten seconds, and whilst comments auto-refresh, you have to scroll up and hit a link to refresh the answers.

Comment: Is it bad if I *do* press F5 every ten seconds? :-S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The program is ill-formed as per 14.6/8:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

That is whether you instantiate the template or not, the template definition is ill-formed as there is no possible instantiation that will succeed.

Note that this is completely unrelated to SFINAE: Substitution Failure is not an Error is part of the *substitution* process, and never takes into account the contents of the template.

Comment: As it says, no diagnostic required, but it would be nice if compilers tried harder to diagnose such things.

Comment: @bames53: Compilers have a tendency to do the least possible processing of templates. In this example it is obvious, but there might be other templates that will never yield valid instantiations and are much harder to detect.

Answer (score 1):

Reading more closely, that standard passage says:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed if written using the substituted arguments. [..]

`return 0` is not an expression, so SFINAE does not apply.

The passage goes on:

> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure.

`return 0` has nothing to do with the function type or its template parameter types, so SFINAE still does not apply.